# How to pass in an int in java and return a string

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and trying to figure out something. 
I have trying to write an easy app where I create an array list, ask for fname, sname & mark, then covert the mark to Grade and save fname, sname & grade to the array list.
So far I can save a fname sname and mark to the array list
I can in a different app pass in a mark and return the grade
but I can't figure out how to combine the 2. I know I need to pass the int mark to my other method, then do the conversion but how do I return the string back up?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry didn't quite explain myself... What I am trying to do is:
`[code]
if(mark < 40){
System.out.println(" Your Grade is: Fail");
GradeValue = "Fail";
return GradeValue;
}
[/code]`

so mark is passed in, then I want to pass up the string value of the grade to write it to the array list. Or do I need to pass down the other values & write them to the array in this method?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`String.valueOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)) or [`Integer.toString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29) like

```
return String.valueOf(1);
```

or

```
return Integer.toString(1);
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment,

```
if(mark < 40){ 
  System.out.println(" Your Grade is: Fail"); 
  GradeValue = "Fail"; 
  return GradeValue; 
}
```

looks ok. But I'd recommend

```
if (mark < 40) {
  System.out.println(" Your Grade is: Fail"); 
  return "Fail";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Following method returns integer when string is passed

```
public int getInteger(String string){
return Integer.parseInt(string);
}
```

Following method returns string when integer is passed

```
public String getString(int integer){
return integer+"";// or String.valueOf(integer);
}
```